# How to detect when a BLE CBPeripheral stops advertising

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I'm writing an app that is using BLE to connect an iPhone to an iPad, and want a screen that shows all the currently broadcasting devices. Is there a way to do this reliably? I've gotten it to work for a minute or two, but after that I believe the peripheral changes its ID and the CBPeripheralDelegate method peripheral(:didModifyServices:) stops being called. Is there a reliable way to detect when a CBPeripheral stops advertising, or at least a way to detect what the ID chagned to? Am I thinking about this all in the wrong way?

Comment: You would typically scan with the "allow duplicates key" and use a timer to age a list of scanned peripherals.

Comment: That did it, thanks! @Pau